Can't seem to correctly install geckodriver on manjaro
I am trying to install geckodriver on manjaro. But when running this simple script
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

I get the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joaquin/OneDrive/linux/UPM/year2/sem1/pcd/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/joaquin/OneDrive/linux/UPM/year2/sem1/pcd/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 71, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/home/joaquin/OneDrive/linux/UPM/year2/sem1/pcd/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/home/joaquin/OneDrive/linux/UPM/year2/sem1/pcd/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/joaquin/OneDrive/linux/UPM/year2/sem1/pcd/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/joaquin/OneDrive/linux/UPM/year2/sem1/pcd/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127

I first tried installing geckodriver with pamac, but it installed version 0.34, which won't work with the current version of Firefox, as said by another error message. Then, I tried to install it with the GitHub repository, following these steps:
sudo mkdir /opt/geckodriver
sudo tar -xvf geckodriver-v0.35.0-linux64.tar.gz -C /opt/geckodriver
echo 'export PATH="/opt/geckodriver:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc

And I got to install it correctly according to my terminal, but I got the error above when running the Python script.
When doing driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/opt/geckodriver/'), Python threw an error saying that was not an available parameter to pass to the function.
Finally, I removed the /opt/geckodriver forlder, and tried to install it with this PKGBUILD. But it still doesn't work.
What can I do to make it work?
